# getting elements randomly from table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an ArrayList, and I need to be able to click a button and then randomly pick out a string from that list and display it in a messagebox.

I'm working with Entity Framework 6.x and I have a table Questions.

I want to randomly get 10 elements from this table, and this is the code I tried :

```
List<Question> GetQuestionsRandomly()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return context.Questions.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(10).ToList();
}
```

but I got this error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Next()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `Random.Next` use `Guid` to random order the records. like:

```
return context.Questions.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
```

You are getting the error because LINQ expression will be translated into underlying data source language, *(probably SQL in your case)*, and since `Random.Next` is not implemented to be converted to SQL, you get the exception.

Comment: thanks, could you please explain how this Guid.NewGuid() works in the above example ?

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU, Guid generated will be unique, so you will be getting a random order each time, plus `Guid.NewGuid` will be translated to `NEWID()` in SQL , so your SQL oder by would be something like `Order by NEWID()` , Use a profiler and check the generated SQL to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Guid`:

```
using (var db = new DataStore())
            {
                var entities = db.Questions
                              .OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid())
                              .Take(numOfEntries);
                  return result.ToList();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use rnd.Next()) in the query because it's not translatable to SQL. Use a guid instead:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 return context.Questions.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: this won't work as it will generate only one number.

Comment: In this case is not generating a random value for every row, I'm not sure that the result is going to be different each time

Comment: That's true, I didn't consider it. Changing to guid.